# Laravel 5 Carbon Format Date

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, php-carbon

How to return this date format 2015-07-01T00:00:00.000-00:00 with Carbon in Laravel ?

Comment: What did you get? What do you expect ? Update your questions so it would be more understandable

Comment: Here's the official documentation for Carbon: http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Comment: I see the official documentation but i cant format this specific date 2015-07-01T00:00:00.000-00:00.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this should be the right format.

But the milliseconds format seems to work only from php 7.0.0 [Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

```
Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.vP');
```

Comment: Thanks, but is not equal, this return your method format. return: 2017-09-04T19:51:32.000000 00:00

Comment: Aha, sorry, now i see, it should be milliseconds instead of microseconds. I updated it.